# "Missing letters (?)", a Nazo-like

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

This was an attempt at making a Nazo-type puzzle.
Nazo puzzles are lateral thinking puzzles, centered around a single neat observation/realisation, as a way to let you find that interesting realisation too.

### What is the 5-character answer that has been covered?

[image: Image with text divided on two sides of the picture, where each line is a pair of strings. In reading order, ...UN / --------N, ......G.... / L---W, Y.... / N---, .....NK / FL---A-, and DA....... / ?????. The final line is missing the right half of the pair.]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is:

> D---- (DOT in morse code (D --- -) ) !

Taking the

> red dots and blue dashes as [morse code](https://wordsmithingtools.com/ultimate-puzzle-solving-chart)*, we have:
>   SUN | MOON
>   HIGH | LOW
>   YES | NO
>   SINK | FLOAT
>   DASH | ?????
>  Which are all opposites!
>  So the missing entry is DOT, the opposite of a DASH in morse code; which in the current format is these 5 characters: D---- (thanks caPNCApn for pointing out my initial goof; I had typed this up too fast without reading it carefully).

- Disclaimer: I made that webpage to solve puzzles like this more quickly. If I shouldn't link to it, delete it.

Comment: Congrats! Also, wow that page is actually really great, if anything more people should see it. I don't see any reason to intentionally limit resources if it's there.  Certainly will being saving it for later!